# My SD card slot doesn't work

Tags: macbook-pro, sd-card

My SD card slot on the latest MacBook (Mid 2012) won't mount my SD card. The SD card doesn't appear in Finder, Disk Utility, Image Capture or anywhere. I know it's not a software problem, because nothing changed before and after. How do I fix it?

Comment: I can't post a new answer because of the protected status of the question.  For me, blowing into the slot didn't work.  I spoke to Apple support who suggested resetting NVRAM and SMC, and this does seem to have helped. In particular, it seems to be the SMC reset that helped.

Comment: @PeterT Please make an edit to the main answer with your details - I will approve that addition if someone else doesn't do it before I see the edit.

Comment: Actually, I think I was just lucky the first time I tried after the SMC reset.  The problem was always intermittent, and I guess likely more related to dust etc after all.

Comment: @PeterT You have to blow really hard. Trust me. It works.

Comment: @Andremoniy had a bit of a double take when that notification appeared on my phone; looked like spam out of context :)... Anyway, it works now, I don't know what fixed it.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

I blew hard in the SD card hub. Now it is working fine.

Comment: Wow.  That worked!  I guess we're back to the days of the NES.

Comment: Are you freakin' kidding me? How the heck did this work... I can confirm that this fixed the issue...

Comment: what the hell, can't believe am upvoting this 

Comment: Can confirm this works

Comment: Hahaha! This worked. Guess we have to keep an eye on dust build up with the card readers. Worked a treat on my iMac. Thanks.

Comment: My girlfriend can't stop laughing after this magic

Comment: Good lord.  It worked!

Comment: Looool, just worked for me!!!

Comment: amazing, that really worked!!!

Comment: son. of. a...i swear

Answer (score 18):

[This thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2459057?threadID=2459057&start=30&tstart=0) says that there's a switch in the SD card slot that detects when a card is inserted, and it can get clogged by dust or jammed or something. If you play around with a toothpick (or anything that fits in that hole), it'll fix your problem. Toggling that switch helps.

Comment: So your issue is fixed?

Comment: Yeah. I only commented because it was a hard bug to find, and much prefer Stack Exchange over some random forum.

Answer (score 10):

for me sticking the SD card in and pulling it a bit out again ( just a few mm ) seems to get it mounted. 
There's even a video that explains how to put it in and pull it out a bit [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nbc0l-t3f1Q)

But I find that putting it in under an angle works better:
Sticking the card in under a angle with the cut off corner against the top of the SD slot and then pushing the card in seems to get it mounted every time.

Comment: +1 for sticking it in under and angle: works reliable up to this point.

Comment: -1 for how ridiculous it is that you pay a premium for this hardware and then have to stuff like that

Comment: I wiggled the card while it’s in the slot and it appeared on the desktop. Great!

Answer (score 3):

My Mac book stop seeing the cards, I used  a can of air to clean out the reader and it works fine now.

Comment: Blowing compressed air into the SD slot on 2 of my MacBook Pros solved the problem. Thanks for that tip. I had tried everything else.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe some dust is stuck in the card slot. To remove, gently blow into the slot and try to insert the card again.

Comment: Could you be slightly more specific.